# R Shapefile map shade based on a lat long point mapped on it

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I have a shape file (distes1) and gps points in Dist_Oulets.  when i plot..

'''ggplot(distes1)+geom_sf()+geom_point(data = Dist_Outlets, aes(x=Retailer.Longitude , y= Retailer.Latitude, color = "red"),alpha = .75, size = 1.5)'''

I get this result.
[image]

**Now, How can i shade the specific area in the map on which the RED lat long point are located?**

Comment: Jou will need to spatially join the points to the regions they are in. This can be done with the sf-package. Without sample data, I cannot provide a better answer than this.

Comment: Thank you Wimpel. was able to do.  any idea how to plot 2 different shape file. eg, i have a country shapefile and roapmap in another , both shapefiles. how to map one over the other?